# _forward in magento does not work

Tags: magento, forward

In my magento controller i used `$this->_forward('form');` inside the index function.
Here the 'form' is another function in the same controller. In my case it does not forward to that function.
Please can anyone tell me what is happening?

Comment: The function must be named 'formAction' in order to work.

Comment: Thanx for the suggenstion but I already have named it formAction, I know that controller functions have Action postfix in them.Any other suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The complete API for _forward() is

protected function _forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null)

So make sure you are forwarding it to an action or try putting multiple parameters